# iteration through JSON Object fails at TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, mariadb, timestamp

I want to get through all the JSON data which is presented by the MySQL(MariaDB) DB Response.

I found a function to iterate through to get & log the key:values pairs.

After that I want to send all this values in a table as HTML (at the moment I don't know, how to do it easily, but that's the next step.)
(maybe I can create dynamically table with the information if its an Object or a key:value pair by creating the "ul - li" structure to be able to send as body to my "view" - or maybe there is a better solution to do that..)

The Data which the DB response looks like:

```js
[
  {
    ID: 5,
    UID: 'E123456',
    LogDate: 2023-03-24T12:55:25.000Z,
    SensorName: 'Sensor1',
    SensorValue: '20.01'
  },
  {
    ID: 6,
    UID: 'E123456',
    LogDate: 2023-03-24T12:55:45.000Z,
    SensorName: 'Sensor1',
    SensorValue: '21.20'
  }
]
```

The function for iterate the JSON is:

```js
function iterateRecursively(object, callbackFunction) {
    // Walk through object
    for (var keyName in object) {
        // If the given parameter is an object, call the function over and 
        // over again, till you get a string or number        

        if (typeof object[keyName] === 'object') {
            console.log("Object - Typeof : " + typeof(keyName));
            iterateRecursively(object[keyName], callbackFunction);
        } else {
            // Callback function to do something with results outside of main function
            if (typeof callbackFunction === 'function') {
                callbackFunction(keyName, object[keyName]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the request to DB and logging the data:

```js
let data = await db.getSensorData(FzID);

iterateRecursively(data, function (key, value) {
 console.log(key + " = " + value + "(" + typeof(key) + " : " + typeof(value) + ")");
    });
```

Console Log:

```js
Object - Typeof : string
ID = 5(string : number)
UID = E123456(string : string)
Object - Typeof : string
SensorName = Sensor1(string : string)
SensorValue = 20.01(string : string)
Object - Typeof : string
ID = 6(string : number)
UID = E123456(string : string)
Object - Typeof : string
SensorName = Sensor1(string : string)
SensorValue = 21.20(string : string)
```

The Type of LogDate Column in DB is "**timestamp**"

**Why is LogDate ignored and how can I get these values?** thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple, the LogDate is of type "object". The array you pass in is also type "object". So to make it work as you want you need to check if it is not Date or Array since Array is also type "object".

```
var obj = object[keyName];
if (typeof obj === 'object' && !(obj instanceof Date) && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
    console.log("Object - Typeof : " + typeof(keyName));
    iterateRecursively(object[keyName], callbackFunction);
}
```